# Moved View in UITableViewCell resets after UILabel SetText is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside this `UITableViewCell` are a few `UILabel`s and a `UIView` to contain some elements. My layout looks something like this:

```
|-TableCell
    |-ContentView
        |-containerView
        |   |- assignTime (UILabel)
        |   |- assignIcon (UIImage)
        |   |- secondaryAssignTime (UILabel)
        |   |- secondaryAssignIcon (UIImage)
        |-Button 1
```

My `UILabels` are tied to a single `NSTimer` set to fire every half second. The Timers display the difference between a set time and now. All of the this works fine. The issue happens when I move `Container View` I can move it fine, but as soon as the `NSTimer` fires and updates the text in the Timer labels the view resets back to its original position. Now, this only happens for the text, if I update the images nothing unusual happens, the `Container View` stays where I put it.

Here is the code I use for updating the `Container View's` position:

```
-(void) updateIndent{
    int indent = 20;
    CGRect f = self.contentView.frame;
    f.size.width = f.size.width - self.myUnit.depth * indent;
    f.origin.x = f.origin.x + self.myUnit.depth * indent;
    self.containerView.frame = f;
    [self.containerView updateConstraints];
}
```

And the code used to update the Timers and Images:

```
-(void) updateCountdown{
    Assignment *a = [self.myUnit getPrimaryAssignment];
    if(a){
        [self.assignTime setText:[a getTimeRemaining]];
        [self.assignIcon setBackgroundImage:[a getIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.assignTime setText:@""];
        [self.assignIcon setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    Assignment *s = [_myUnit getSecondaryAssignment];
    if(s){
        [self.secondaryAssignTime setText:[s getTimeRemaining]];
        [self.secondaryAssignIcon setBackgroundImage:[s getIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.secondaryAssignTime setText:@""];
        [self.secondaryAssignIcon setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

So, to recap, when I call `updateIndent` the view updates as expected. When I call `updateCountdown` if a `setText` method is called the view resets back to its original position.

**EDIT**

I tried moving everything outside of `containerView` and it still had the same affect. I also tried to see if it had something to do with my `getTimeRemaining` by replacing it with a literal string and still the same. I update my text and the `containerView` resets its position.

**EDIT 2**

I added some breakpoints to see if I could see exactly when the view resets itself. I added breakpoints to these lines

```
Assignment *a = [self.myUnit getPrimaryAssignment];
Assignment *s = [_myUnit getSecondaryAssignment];
[self.secondaryAssignIcon setBackgroundImage:[s getIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And *after* this line in `updateIndent`

```
[self.containerView updateConstraints];
```

What I found was the view doesn't move to its new position in any of these places. In theory, the view should have been updated by the time `updateCountdown` got called.

**EDIT 3**

I decided to call `updateIndent` after `updateCountdown` in the `NSTimer`. What I found was the view only gets updated when the text changes, *not* just when `setText` is called. So, I have a better understanding of the sequence of events.

1. `updateIndent` is called and view gets its new position
2. Timer fires and calls `updateCountdown` setting timer text to "00:00" clearing the indent
3. `updateIndent` is called to set the indent
4. Timer fires and calls `updateCountdown` setting timer text to "00:00" **indent is unchanged**
5. `updateIndent` is called to set the indent
6. Timer fires and calls `updateCountdown` setting timer text to "00:01" clearing the indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this fixed. I created an outlet to the constraints I was editing. So rather than using the `updateIndent` method described above I reworked it to simply update one constraint.

```
self.indentMargin.constant = self.myUnit.depth * indent;
```